# use SQLCipher in Apache Cordova App

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, sqlcipher

I have decided to use `SQLCipher` in a cordova android app, in order to encipher my sqlite dtabase. To make use of it, I follow the instructions here: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/README.org

I fail here:

> Update the import path from android.database.sqlite.* to
>   net.sqlcipher.database.* in any source files that reference it. The
>   original android.database.Cursor can still be used unchanged.

After I added the buildpath and replace all references to the importpath as stated above, `cordova -d build` fails.

```
Error: /opt/lampp/htdocs/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try to open Android project. This error info is general when Android Update Fails. Yo will get the origin error...